# finding a tubular neighborhood

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Assume $f \colon M \to N$ is a smooth mapping between smooth manifolds. Assume $U \subset M$ and $V \subset N$ are submanifolds.
Assume $f(U) \subset V$ and $(d_xf)^{-1}\left(T_{f(x)}V\right) = T_xU$.

Can I know find a neighborhood $U \subset Z$, s.th. for all $x \in Z \setminus U$ we have $f(x) \not \in V$?

Comment: Here's a hint: If not, you can create a sequence of points $z_n\in Z$ with $f(z_n)\in V$ and $z_n\to x\in U$, and you can arrange (with appropriate subsequences) that the limit of chords from $x$ to $z_n$ will not be tangent to $U$. This will tell you that $(d_xf)^{-1}(T_{f(x)}V)$ strictly contains $T_xU$.

Comment: So if I take a riemannian metric an $M$, and I find such a sequence $z_n \in Z$ of points. Then I find 1) a subsequence of points, s.th. $dist(z_{n+1},x) < dist(z_n,x)$, 2) s.th. for $\gamma_n$ being the geodesic from $x$ to $z_n$ and $v_n = \dot \gamma_n(0)/ ||\dot \gamma_n(0)||$ the sequence $v_n \to v_0$. So and now $v_0 \in (d_xf)^{-1}\left(T_{f(x)}V\right)$ but $v_0 \not \in T_xU$? But how to prove that?